# Reasoning around my State Store Design - UI vs App State

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am getting a little confused between application state and UI state. When a user selects an activity from a list on the page, an API call is made to fetch the announcements for the selected activity. Is the selected activity id considered UI or application state? Should the selected activity id be stored in the sale-activity slice OR should it go into a dedicated UI slice, for example sale-activity-listing?

Here is my current structure.

```
{
    "entities": {
        "sale-activities": {
            "1": { "id": 1, "vehicleId": 3, "status": "pending" },
            "2": { "id": 2, "vehicleId": 3, "status": "completed" }
        },
        "sale-activity-announcements": {
            "4": { "id": 1, "saleActivityId": 1, "description": "Announcement 4" },
            "5": { "id": 2, "saleActivityId": 1, "description": "Announcement 5" },
            "6": { "id": 1, "saleActivityId": 2, "description": "Announcement 6" },
            "7": { "id": 2, "saleActivityId": 2, "description": "Announcement 7" }
        }
    },
    "sale-activities": {
        "loaded": true,
        "loading": false,
        "ids": [1, 2],
        "offset": 0,
        "selectedActivityId": 1
    },
    "sale-activity-announcements": {
        "1": {
            "loaded": true,
            "loading": false,
            "ids": [4, 5]
        },
        "2": {
            "loaded": true,
            "loading": false,
            "ids": [6, 7]
        }
    },
    "selectedVehicleId": 3
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: does the design make sense? like i mentioned, this is my first time/attempt at this.

Comment: I did not understand the question, please write your question directly focusing on the information you want to know! thanks!

Comment: ok, the questions should be more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that there's really a separation between application and ui state in this scenario--it's all "ui application" state to me. I see nothing wrong with how you have this structured though.